# HTML removes placeholder content when set to input type set to number

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova

I look to have an input box with the following written in it "Enter your Contact Number". But when the user taps the box to enter their phone number I just want the numeric pad to appear. To do this I set the input box's type to number but when doing so it removes the placeholder text. Here is some code:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Enter your Contact Number"/>
```

Any idea how I can have the placeholder content appear and also have a number pad appear when the box is tapped on?

Note: I'm using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile on Android

Comment: By the HTML5 spec, you should not use `input type=number` for data that is not numeric but e.g. a contact number. But if you do, normal browsers still let you specify a `placeholder` attribute. So at least “HTML” does not remove placeholder content.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below format:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="Contact Number" />
```

Comment: Tried your solution but no such luck, thanks for the post though

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `type=number` to `type=tel`. The placeholder will be displayed with the numeric-keyboard.